# XSLT streaming is too slow with if conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

We are using saxon-ee streaming to process big-file. In this case, the file size is around 1gb. the transformation is doing order lookup data and filtering the matching order_id.

The transformation takes about 1.5 hours. when I use the lookup/filtering.

If I comment out the lookup and if checks, it takes only 2 mins to transform the complete file.

It seems to be an issue with the way I am using a lookup and if condition. Please provide some suggestions to fix this performance issue.
sample input XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
   <order>
      <guid>3079866431</guid>
      <name>name1</name>
   </order>
   <order>
      <guid>3079866431</guid>
      <name>name2</name>
   </order>
   <order>
      <guid>2583715475</guid>
      <name>name3</name>
   </order>
</orders>
```

lookup.xml file content

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?><IndexControl><entry id="2521202370" status="true"/><entry id="2583715475" status="true"/></IndexControl>
```

XSLT template with lookups takes 1.5 hours

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>    
    <xsl:variable name="IndexLookup" select="document('https://test.com/lookup.xml')/IndexControl"/>
    <xsl:template match="orders">
        <xsl:element name="Batch">            
            <xsl:for-each select="order ! copy-of(.)">              
                 <xsl:variable name="order_id" select="guid"/>
              <xsl:if test="$IndexLookup/entry[@id=$order_id]/@status = 'true'">
                <xsl:element name="Order">
                    <xsl:element name="Field">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">id</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="guid"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="Field">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">name</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>                  
                </xsl:element>               
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>           
        </xsl:element>       
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT without lookup takes 2 mins

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>    
    <!-- <xsl:variable name="IndexLookup" select="document('https://test.com/lookup.xml')/IndexControl"/> -->
    <xsl:template match="orders">
        <xsl:element name="Batch">            
            <xsl:for-each select="order ! copy-of(.)">               
                <xsl:variable name="order_id" select="guid"/>
              <!-- <xsl:if test="$IndexLookup/entry[@id=$order_id]/@status = 'true'"> -->
                <xsl:element name="Order">
                    <xsl:element name="Field">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">id</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="guid"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="Field">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">name</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>                  
                </xsl:element>               
               <!--  </xsl:if> -->
            </xsl:for-each>           
        </xsl:element>       
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a key `<xsl:key name="lookup" match="IndexControl/entry" use="@id"/>` and then use `<xsl:for-each select="order ! copy-of(.)[key('lookup', guid, doc('https://test.com/lookup.xml'))/@status = 'true']">`.

Comment: This is the content of lookup.xml file `<?xml version="1.0"?><IndexControl><entry id="2521202370" status="true"/><entry id="2583715475" status="true"/></IndexControl>`. Sorry I am not clear about this line [key('lookup', guid, doc('https://test.com/lookup.xml'))/@status = 'true'] Could you please explain?

Comment: @Gopinath, consider to add any code to your question, it will be more readable there than in a comment.

Comment: @Gopinath, what is unclear or unknow to you, any use of keys for lookup, the use of a predicate? The declaration `<xsl:key name="lookup" match="IndexControl/entry" use="@id"/>` is basically a hint to the XSLT processor to build an index/a lookup table or hashmap for those `entry` elements based on the `id` attribute value. And then, instead of doing the comparison you had, the answer uses that index/key and I have also moved the check from a nested `xsl:if` directly into a predicate on the processed and materialized `order` element your `for-each` works with.

Comment: Thanks, @Martin. I have added the sample XML and index look-up files to the question. Let me try this approach and see if works

Comment: @Gopinath, see you in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

I would have expected the Saxon-EE optimiser to generate an index for the lookup expression, if I get a chance I will investigate why this is not happening. But certainly, using an explicit key as Martin Honnen suggests should fix it.

For streaming large files I usually reckon that around 1 minute per gigabyte is a reasonable target, but it obviously depends on the work you are doing and the machine you are running it on.

Incidentally, it won't affect performance, but I do find this kind of code very unreadable:

```
 <xsl:element name="Field">
      <xsl:attribute name="name">name</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
           <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:element>
```

when you could write instead:

```
<Field name="name" value="{name}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Michael. Please investigate and let me know

Comment: I ran it through Saxon from the command line with the -explain option and confirmed that the filter expression isn't indexed. The reason is that the optimization is run with a flag `optimizeForStreaming` set. This reflects that filter expressions on a streamed input can't be indexed. However, we should be able to detect that although we're streaming, this particular expression isn't affected by streaming. I'll raise an issue on this.

Comment: You can track progress by putting a watch on https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5475

Comment: The issue is now resolved (awaiting next maintenance release).